# Getting a program to loop within its self

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need help getting this program to loop within its self after it runs the first time. It asks the user if they want to encode, decode or exit. The program runs, it encodes/decodes like it should. I now need to get another Pane to pop up and ask if they user wants to code another input then loop through everything it ran through the first time. I have the pane to where it asks the user if they want to run again but cant get it to loop through the coder.

```
public void encoding()
{
    int userChoice;
    int i;
    int p=1;
    int counter=0;
    counter++;
    String fin = "";

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Want to ENCODE, DECODE or EXIT? Press 
    1, 2, or 3");
    userChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);    


    if (userChoice == 1 )
            {
                String encode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What Are We 
                Encoding? ");

                char[] array = encode.toCharArray();      

                for(i=0; i <array.length; i++)
                    {                            
                        char Ecode = encode.charAt(i);
                        Ecode--;
                        Ecode--;
                        fin += Character.toString(Ecode);

                    }         

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fin);
            }       

        else if (userChoice == 2)
            {
                    String decode =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What Are We 
                    Decoding? ");

                    char[] array1 = decode.toCharArray();

                    for(i=0; i < array1.length; i++)
                    {              
                        char Dcode = decode.charAt(i);
                        Dcode++;
                        Dcode++; 
                        fin += Character.toString(Dcode);
                    }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,fin);

                    String again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Want to code another?
                    Press 1 or 2");

                    int aChoice = Integer.parseInt(again);

                    if (aChoice==1)
                        { 
                            System.out.print("bob"); 
                        }

                    else 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good Bye");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap you code starting `int i;`  and include `if-else block` in a `do-while` loop as:

```
      do{
         int i;
         int p=1;
         .....
         .....
      }while(userChoice != 3);
```

Please Note: This will not let you exit, until you enter `3`.

You may want to add another block to handle th conditions when user enters anything other that 1,2 or 3.

Alternatively, you can do like:

```
      do{
         String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog...
         .....
         .....
       }while(userChoice == 1 || userChoice == 2);
```

This will exit the loop for any choice other than 1 or 2.

EDIT: Please find below the fixed code:

```
public void encoding(){
    int userChoice, i;
    do{
        String fin = "";
        String input = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Want to ENCODE, DECODE or EXIT? Press 1, 2, or 3");
        userChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);    

        if (userChoice == 1 ){
        String encode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What Are We Encoding?");
        char[] array = encode.toCharArray();      
        for(i=0; i <array.length; i++){                            
        char Ecode = encode.charAt(i);
        Ecode--;
        Ecode--;
        fin += Character.toString(Ecode);
        }         
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fin);
    } else if (userChoice == 2) {
        String decode =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What Are We Dencoding?");
            char[] array1 = decode.toCharArray();
            for(i=0; i < array1.length; i++){              
       char Dcode = decode.charAt(i);
       Dcode++;
       Dcode++; 
       fin += Character.toString(Dcode);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fin);
     }
    }while(userChoice != 3);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good Bye");
    System.exit(0);
   }
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I do the do while loop the encoded/decoded messages of each run are added to the message of the current run. the first time you encode "qqq" you get "ooo" when you then decode "qqq" it gives you "ooosss" instead of just "sss".

Comment: @TorreSledge Make sure you wrap almost all encoding/decoding pattern code inside the loop. If you need help, please let me know.

Comment: I have my entire code from the String input to the end of my second else if statement wrapped in the Do While. I continues to add the code of the last run with each run after.

Comment: @TorreSledge There was a very small problem. Move `String fin = "";` inside `do-while` loop, as it needs to re re-initialized. Added a sample code completely working in java for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could enclose the `JOptionPane` inputs + the full corresponding `if` block in a `while` loop:

```
int userChoice = 0;
while (userChoice != 3) {

  int i;
  int p=1;
  // the rest of the params here

   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)
   ...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, when I do the do while loop the encoded/decoded messages of each run are added to the message of the current run. the first time you encode "qqq" you get "ooo" when you then decode "qqq" it gives you "ooosss" instead of just "sss"

Comment: Move every parameter except for `userChoice` inside the loop.